# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error (downloading from Nuget for Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am having this error on my VS when I am trying to download some versions of xamarin.android.support (v24 and up) from nugget package manager

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 
26.1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1'
```

How can I solve this? I'm sorry but I don't have any idea about MonoAndroid.
I already tried to update may xamarin and vs but still having same error. TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Android Support 26.x Libraries require "targeting" Android 8.0+

> The Target Framework (also known as compileSdkVersion) is the specific Android framework version (API level) that your app is compiled for at build time.

In your `Xamarin.Android` application project, set the `Target Framework` to 8.0/Oreo

[image]

re: Xamarin Android Doc: [Target Framework](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Target_Framework)