# Android App times out in development

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

when I try to run my app through Visual Studio 2017 I sometimes encounter a timeout issue. I'm not really sure what I did wrong. But the app ran without any issues when I create a project. But when I make a change to the application, I receive an error. [image of error][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnh84.png

Code here..

```
namespace App3 {


    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("C:\\Users\\maste\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\App3\\App3\\App3\\Main" +
        "Page.xaml")]
    public partial class MainPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger stops at **global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));** with the error **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException:**

Very new to Android development within visual studio 2017 using xamarin.forms. What am I doing wrong? How can improve my environment? I also have another issue when building the project, it never builds. So I have to cancel the build. When I cancel the build the original problem becomes apparent.

Comment: Enable the Xaml Compiler to help in determining the errors in your XAML:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: Just add :[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]? Above namespace

Comment: Did that... now I get these warnings, The$(TargetFrameworkVersion)for xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll(vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion for your version (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameowrkVersion) for your project.

Comment: I wrote previous comment before your last comment. I am doing that right now.

Comment: Set the "Target Framework"  to 8.0/Oreo:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745689/severity-code-description-project-file-line-suppression-state-error-downloading/47745796#47745796

Comment: I actually do not get that option.

Comment: In your **Xamarin.Android application project**, set the Target Framework to 8.0/Oreo

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you for your help. But, how do I update the target Framework options.

Comment: The highest Framework I currently have is 7.1

Comment: Make sure the you have the Android 8.0/API27 installed via the Android SDK manager and update your Xamarin installation *if needed* to include Xamarin.Android
Version: 8.1.X.X : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-sdk/

Comment: I will work on your advice. Unfortunately I have to run. Do you mind if I message you? Or link you later on in this thread?

Comment: Please post your `MainPage.xaml` code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, your problem is obvious. You need to install the Android 8.0 which corresponds with API27. You can do this in the Android SDK Manager. Here is a link which you might find helpful :
https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/07/09/troubleshooting-the-default-install-of-xamarin-with-visual-studio-2017-and-windows-10-creators-update/

Or this other one which shows how to install required android sdk components : https://docs.elementscompiler.com/VisualStudio/Setup/AndroidSDK/#installing-required-android-sdk-components

You can find Android SDK Manager in visual studio in :

`Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager`.

Although I have a question : Why are you targeting only android version 8.0?
If you want to avoid these updates you can just target another version of android. You can do this in the android project:

```
Properties -> Application -> Target Framework (and choose framework 7.1)
```

Hope my answer helps. :)

Comment: It helped get rid of the warnings. But the Build takes so long. It never finishes building for some reason.

Comment: Have you installed `android wear Arm eabi v7a system image` from android sdk manager?  After you install it than just restart your adb server from :
`Tools -> Android -> Restart adb Server`
Also try to restart your visual studio, clean project and delete bin and obj files.
Let me know if it works.