# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I am working on a PCL project in Xamarin, when I installed the Xamarin.Forms.Maps package, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

when looking for the same error information, I find very little, I have tried updating the Xamarin.Android.Support package and it will not let me .... I attached my android options

[image: Android Options]

what am I doing wrong? Does it have to do with the updates of Xamarin Forms to .NET standard? or do I just have a combination of badly installed packages?
I attach my installed packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="4.0.0-beta125" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="2.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.5.1.444934" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

any help for me? greetings and thank you

Comment: `I have tried updating the Xamarin.Android.Support package and it will not let me` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745689/severity-code-description-project-file-line-suppression-state-error-downloading/47745796#47745796 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246580/xamarin-how-to-update-mono-android-version-to-resolve-dependencies/49248192#49248192